# NOOB query on select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have following tables and data.

**Bugs**

```
bug_id creator category_id change_request_id
1       john        101         123
2       mark        124         124
3       mark        139         135
4       shane       167         148
6       logan       278         234
```

**Category**

```
id  owner category_name
101 mark    abc
124 john    def
139 mark    ghi
167 mark    jkl 
278 mark    mno
```

**Change_request**

```
id  creator
123 mark
124 mark
135 mark
148 john
234 mark
```

I am required to extract all the bugs from bug table whose creator field value is john or whose category owner is john (which is nothing but owner field of category table) or whose change_request "creator" is john.

I have written a simple select statement to achieve this

```
SELECT bug_id
  FROM bugs
     ,category
     ,change_request
 WHERE ((bugs.creator = 'john'
              )
           OR ((bugs.category_id = category.id
                     )
                 AND (category.owner = 'john'
                     )
              )
           OR ((bugs.change_request_id = change_request.id
                     )
                 AND (change_request.creator = 'john'
                     )
              )
       );
```

But when I use the above query, it takes too long to execute. All my table columns are properly indexed. Is there an optimized query to solve my purpose?

Comment: 10g? 11g? Which one is it?

Comment: Avoid using deprecated syntax, using standard `JOIN` syntax will be cleaner and easier to troubleshoot if nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

The query optimizer may handle this more easily:

```
SELECT bug_id
  FROM bugs
    JOIN category ON bugs.category_id = category.id
    JOIN change_request ON bugs.change_request_id = change_request.id
WHERE (bugs.creator = 'john') 
  OR (category.owner = 'john')
  OR (change_request.creator = 'john');
```

You could write the same thing with the comma operator and only `WHERE` predicates, but the resulting where clause would not be identical to yours (though it would evaluate the same way).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Voting up & marking as answer

Answer (score 1):

To add to John Bollinger's answer, the reason *why* it is taking too long is because of the result Cartesian joins in your `WHERE` clause. The `OR` in the `WHERE` clause makes the join conditions not mandatory.

For example if `bugs.creator` is `JOHN`, your other predicates are ignored resulting in the `JOHN` records joined with ***ALL*** the records in both `category` and `change_request` tables.

John's query would remove this undesirable effect as it correctly puts the join conditions and the filter predicates where they belong.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. Voting up